# Display thousands of mysql records in my jtable

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jtable

I have a few more 2 million values into my MySQL database. And i want to display all this values in my JTable. But i couldn't. The Java heap out space. But, i know solve this, but, the JTable will load after too long, right ?

Is there a way where can i load this in a few seconds, 1m or 2m ?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to load the entire lot? Typically you'd use pagination to solve this type of thing, either with infinity style scrolling (like facebook for example) or page numbers at the bottom of the `JTable`

Comment: @ChrisTurner I think it is possible to slice it, in 2 with 1 million or 4 with 500k. But, this way do you think solve my problem ?

Comment: Whatever problem you are trying to solve, I am certain that displaying two million of anything in a user interface is NOT the answer. Maybe you should take a step back and tell us about the underlying problem? Or maybe I am not understanding what you are asking?

Comment: @Rob How i said. The "Problem", actually, is the time that my JTable are taking to display my values, which is so, so, so long